# NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon MTA: server SMTP socket wedged: exiting

Tags: daemon, sendmail

```
host map: lookup ( ): deferred
```

It is the log info in mailq.

```
NOQUEUE: SYSERR(root): opendaemonsocket: daemon MTA: server SMTP socket wedged: exiting
```

It is the log at /etc/log/maillog

I use sendmail to send mail.
I can use 'mail' to mail to local users, but I cannot mail to others.
For example, I sent a mail to example@gmail.com, which could not run. A mail to root can be sent and received.